# linearK error in seq. default() cannot be NA, NaN

Tags: spatstat

I am trying to learn linearK estimates on a small linnet object from the CRC spatstat book (chapter 17) and when I use the linearK function, spatstat throws an error. I have documented the process in the comments in the r code below. The error is as below.

```
Error in seq.default(from = 0, to = right, length.out = npos + 1L) : 'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
```

I do not understand how to resolve this. I am following this process:

```
# I have data of points for each data of the week
# d1 is district 1 of the city. 
# I did the step below otherwise it was giving me tbl class
d1_data=lapply(split(d1, d1$openDatefactor),as.data.frame)

# I previously create a linnet and divided it into districts of the city
d1_linnet = districts_linnet[["d1"]]

# I create point pattern for each day
d1_ppp = lapply(d1_data, function(x) as.ppp(x, W=Window(d1_linnet)))
plot(d1_ppp[[1]], which.marks="type")

# I am then converting the point pattern to a point pattern on linear network
d1_lpp <- as.lpp(d1_ppp[[1]], L=d1_linnet, W=Window(d1_linnet))


d1_lpp
Point pattern on linear network
3 points
15 columns of marks: ‘status’, ‘number_of_’, ‘zip’, ‘ward’, 
‘police_dis’, ‘community_’, ‘type’, ‘days’, ‘NAME’, 
‘DISTRICT’, ‘openDatefactor’, ‘OpenDate’, ‘coseDatefactor’, 
‘closeDate’ and ‘instance’
Linear network with 4286 vertices and 6183 lines
Enclosing window: polygonal boundary
enclosing rectangle: [441140.9, 448217.7] x [4640080, 4652557] units

# the errors start from plotting this lpp object
plot(d1_lpp)

"show.all" is not a graphical parameter
 Show Traceback
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values

coords(d1_lpp)


 x    y    seg    tp
441649.2    4649853    5426    0.5774863
445716.9    4648692    5250    0.5435492
444724.6    4646320    677     0.9189631
3 rows
```

And then consequently, I also get error on `linearK(d1_lpp)`

```
Error in seq.default(from = 0, to = right, length.out = npos + 1L) : 'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
```

I feel lpp object has the problem, but I find it hard to interpret the errors and how to resolve them. Could someone please guide me?

Thanks

Comment: We need access to your data or a reproducible example using built in datasets or artificial generated data to be able to help.

Comment: I have added the data to this link. [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_2R6KanT3YIQmxFTGVUaVAxYkk). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm there is a bug in `plot.lpp` when trying to plot the marked point pattern on the linear network. That will hopefully be fixed soon. You can plot the unmarked point pattern using

```
plot(unmark(d1_lpp))
```

I cannot reproduce the problem with `linearK`. Which version of `spatstat` are you running? In the development version on my laptop `spatstat_1.51-0.073` everything works. There has been changes to this code recently, so it is likely that this will be solved by updating to development version (see https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat).

Comment: I am using the regular cran version. I have installed from github and linearK seems to work. I will experiment more. Thank you.